# Paging using json file in python

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7

I have this json file which includes information about pages I have retrieving using this 
python code:

```
import facebook # pip install facebook-sdk
import json
import codecs




# Create a connection to the Graph API with your access token

ACCESS_TOKEN = ''#my access token
g = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)


s=g.request('search', { 'q' : '&','type' : 'page', 'limit' : 5000 , 'locale' : 'ar_AR' })





f = open("sampels.txt", 'w')
f.write(json.dumps(s, indent=1))
f.close()


#########################################################
```

this is my samples json file a snapshot of it:

{

```
 "paging": {
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?limit=5000&type=page&q=%26&locale=ar_AR&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAIRlSOXkyk1lIMUIWViAoz5lf5t0pSdsu6lg5ZANJuYMIPZCy5N9KFQoLnpi1oxD8tNIaabWackCO31UYaAGkb38IPHxI33ldbRQDXJ02CtJrwE8NI4mZAz20OznLfuCpypDbxNYF3p9XauZCtoywoS9KJwAgW8NYgZCpD4ZBKfCBR5jjXnbcZD&offset=5000&__after_id=92240239536"
 }, 
 "data": [
  {
   "category": "\u0627\u0644\u062a\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0645", 
   "name": "The London School of Economics and Political Science - LSE", 
   "category_list": [
    {
     "id": "108051929285833", 
     "name": "\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062c\u0627\u0645\u0639\u0629"
    }, 
    {
     "id": "187751327923426", 
     "name": "\u0645\u0646\u0638\u0645\u0629 \u062a\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0645\u064a\u0629"
    }
   ], 
   "id": "6127898346"
  }, 
  {
   "category": "\u0628\u0636\u0627\u0626\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u064a\u0639 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u062a\u062c\u0632\u0626\u0629 \u0648\u0628\u0636\u0627\u0626\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u062a\u0647\u0644\u0643\u064a\u0646", 
   "name": "Stop & Shop", 
   "category_list": [
    {
     "id": "169207329791658", 
     "name": "\u0645\u062d\u0644 \u0628\u0642\u0627\u0644\u0629"
    }
   ], 
   "id": "170000993071234"
  }, 
  {
   "category": "\u0628\u0636\u0627\u0626\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u064a\u0639 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u062a\u062c\u0632\u0626\u0629 \u0648\u0628\u0636\u0627\u0626\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u062a\u0647\u0644\u0643\u064a\u0646", 
   "name": "C&A", 
   "category_list": [
    {
     "id": "186230924744328", 
     "name": "\u0645\u062a\u062c\u0631 \u0645\u0644\u0627\u0628\u0633"
    }
   ], 
   "id": "109345009145382"
  }, 
  {
   "category": "\u0645\u0646\u0638\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0631\u0628\u062d\u064a\u0629", 
   "name": "Rock and Roll Hall of Fame + Museum", 
   "category_list": [
    {
     "id": "396255327112122", 
     "name": "\u0645\u062a\u062c\u0631 \u0645\u0648\u0633\u064a\u0642\u0649"
    },
```

now what I want to do is to get the next field in order to get my next 5000 page into my database. 
I have tried a lot but I couldn't figure out away to do this can any body tell me how to take the next URL and how pass it to the request function I have in my code.?

Answer (score 0):

`g.request()` returns a Python dict which gives you access to the paging/next url. Why do you dump it as json and write it to file instead of just using it ?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand any thing can you simplify your answer

Comment: You have a Python dict with all you need in it. You just have to actuall use it instead of dumping it as json and write it to a file. If you cannot understand this no one on earth can help you.